# Different MySQL charset in and outside Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench, charset

I'm a frontend course student. Recently i'v got DB MySQL homework and base image. One of task was to deploy DB image at Docker, i'v done it successfully.
I was going to inspect DB contents at MySQL Workbench for convinience (and i tried it at phpMyAdmin), but faced to charset troubles as there are russian strings in DB tables.
I've posted the

```
show variables like 'char%';
```

query, but got two different answers:

1. CLI answer (inside Docker)

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                         |
| character_set_connection | latin1                         |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | latin1                         |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8                           |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

2. MySQL Workbench  answer (and other outside Docker)

```
 character_set_client  utf8mb4
character_set_connection  utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem  binary
character_set_results  utf8mb4
character_set_server  utf8mb4
character_set_system  utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/
```

How can i reach the normal view of russian's strings outside the Docker?
[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether the connection in Workbench uses the proper encoding? What's the encoding of that column after all?

Comment: check if workbeck is using proper charset with below option
Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Appearance. Change the Editor font accordingly.

Comment: I've faced with Workbench and SQL only yesterday .
I don't know how to check Workbench connection encoding, can you to point me a way?
At Workbench, the charset of column is "Collation:utf8_bin"